# trying to decompress xref stream from pdf - getting "ERROR incorrect header check"

Tags: javascript, pdf

I am trying to parse the xref stream from PDF in JavaScript. I managed to succesfully isolate the stream itself (I checked that it's ok by comparing it in debugging mode with the value between *steram*. and *endstream* tags in PDF.

However, when I try to inflate it using [pako lib](https://github.com/nodeca/pako), I get an error saying: *ERROR incorrect header check*.

The compression method is *FlateDecode*, which can be seen from the dictionary.

Here is the code in question:

```
const dict = pdfStr.slice(pdf.startXRef);
            const xrefStreamStart = this.getSubstringIndex(dict, 'stream', 1) + 'stream'.length + 2;
            const xrefStreamEnd = this.getSubstringIndex(dict, 'endstream', 1) + 1;
            const xrefStream = dict.slice(xrefStreamStart, xrefStreamEnd);
            const inflatedXrefStream = pako.inflate(this.str2ab(xrefStream), { to: 'string' });


pdfStr is the whole PDF read as a string, while *pdf.startXRef* holds the value of the position of the xref stream object.
```

Here's the whole PDF if someone wants to have a look: https://easyupload.io/lzf9he

**EDIT:** As *mcernak* has suggested I had a problem that I included /r and /n in the stream. However, now that I corrected the code I got a different error: *invalid distance too far back*

Comment: No file is found at the link you provided.

Answer (score 2):

The stream content is located between `stream\r\n` and `\r\nendstream`.

You need to take into account those two additional characters (`\r\n`) at the beginning and at the end to read the correct data:

```
const dict = pdfStr.slice(pdf.startXRef);
const xrefStreamStart = this.getSubstringIndex(dict, 'stream', 1) + 'stream'.length + 2;
const xrefStreamEnd = this.getSubstringIndex(dict, 'endstream', 1) - 2;
const xrefStream = dict.slice(xrefStreamStart, xrefStreamEnd);
const inflatedXrefStream = pako.inflate(this.str2ab(xrefStream), { to: 'string' });
```